Ecu short, no check engine light, 2013 Toyota Corolla s 1.8
I own a 2013 Toyota Corolla S 1.8L that has some sort of electrical issue that has been draining the battery. To help locate where the possible short Maybe I performed a test to where I disconnected the positive battery terminal and connected a 12 volt test light which showed that there was a short. I proceeded to testing the fuses one by one. It was only when I pulled the fuse labeled ECU that the test light went out telling me there must be a short with the ECU. I previously had a 2006 Toyota Camry that had the same issue however I was never able to pinpoint exactly where the short was before trading it in for the Corolla that I now own and is having the same issues. Not sure if this is an issue with Toyotas in particular and I am far from being a mechanic . There is no check engine light on and the car just passed small last month however this issue has been going on for quite some time . Nothing has been modified on the vehicle such as a new stereo install Etc however we have noticed that whenever trying to charge your phone through the cigarette lighter it will actually discharge your phone instead. Not sure if this would be related to the ECU but it does seem suspicious. My question is if it shows a short when I pull out the ECU fuse what would be my next step in finding and correcting the problem. Please help. And thank you in advance.

I have some useful information for you that will put you on the right track to repair, but first I need some details. You can either reply in a comment or EDIT your question to add the info. 1: "Draining the battery" What does this mean exactly? Please be specific. 2: How old is the battery? Look for a date on the battery itself. 3: Describe the test light -- LED? Tail light bulb? Current rating? If you don't know, just give the brand name and model number.

Agreeing with @MTA we'd need more information. One of the things I'd be most interested in is what is the actual power draw on the system. Some amount of power can possibly go to the ECU. If it is drawing 200mA then it probably isn't an issue. If it's drawing 3A, that's a different story. You state it is draining the battery. How long does it take for the battery to go flat? Still, MTA is hot on it, so if you could anser all of these questions, it would be a great help in us helping you. :o)

I used a 16012 Circuit Tester 6V / 12V DC Systems Long Probe Continuity Test Light Car Voltage. I don't know how old the battery is. The cigarette lighter doesn't work and keeps blowing the fuse whenever I replace it. If you plug your phone into the USB port to charge it, it will discharge your phones battery instead of charge it. By draining the battery I mean it is slow to start because the battery is almost dead. But the only fuse that is showing that there is a short is when I pull the ecu fuse.

It seems likely that the circuit board or little module that makes +5 volts for your USB port has an internal fault that acts like a short circuit, and that it runs off the same fuse as the cigarette lighter. That won't drain your battery because if the fuse has blown, no current can flow to that failed device. NOTE: Make sure you don't have a stray coin in the lighter socket.

You haven’t answered the question from @Paulster2 about actual current drain, so I assume that you don’t have a multimeter. You won’t be able to finish diagnosing the problem with just a test light, but it’s a start.
You don’t have a “short with the ECU.”
A short circuit (a “short”) is a condition in which electricity in a wire that is intended to supply power through a device to ground, instead takes a shortcut directly to ground. This almost always results in an immediate blown fuse. If not for the fuse, the wire would overheat and possibly catch fire before melting. The ECU is not blowing a fuse nor catching fire, so you don’t have a short.
What you have is an ECU that is consuming power. But all ECU’s consume some power all the time. You haven’t determined how much power the ECU is consuming because you haven’t measured it, you’ve only used a test light.
A test light that I know of that looks just like your 16012 contains a 3 watt side marker bulb that requires only 250 milliamps (mA) to light up brightly, and about 75-100 mA to light dimly.
An ECU that consumes 250 mA when first connected (engine off, ignition off, battery connected) is completely normal. Many ECUs will reduce their power consumption after 3-5 minutes by going into a low-power standby mode. This can reduce power consumption to 100 mA or less.
So the bottom line is that your testing with a test light has not revealed anything useful about your battery becoming discharged, but it has established an important fact: if you have a parasitic current drain, it can only be by the ECU.
NOW PROVE THAT IT’S NOT THE ECU
Before moving to the battery problem, it might be best to prove beyond doubt that your ECU is not draining your battery. My usual approach to a complex problem is “first fix anything that you know is bad” but a useful corollary is “don’t be distracted by anything that you can prove is good.” So we will first prove that the ECU is not draining your battery.
You’ve already proven that the only fused circuit in the car that is consuming power with the ignition off is protected by the ECU fuse, and we know that its current drain is less than 10 amps because if it were more than 10 amps, your battery would go dead overnight.
Go to that store that sells cheap import tools (or any store of your choice) and buy the digital multimeter that is priced less than $20 and has a separate socket marked 10A. This will allow you to safely measure a current drain up to 10 amps.
Do not connect it between the battery post and battery cable as you did with the test light, as this could damage the meter with a sudden current surge from charging capacitors in the radio and other devices. Instead, start with tightly connected battery cables, and pull the fuse for the ECU.
Be sure the meter is set to the 10 amp DC scale, the red cable is plugged into the 10A socket and the black cable is plugged into the COM or (-) socket. Now use the meter probes to contact both  fuse socket contacts. Current will run through the meter and energize the ECU. Hold the probes steady, and be prepared to hold them in unbroken contact for 5 minutes. If you insert the probes just right, you may get them to stick on their own so you don’t have to hold them. That would be good, because if you break contact at all during the test, you have to start the 5 minute test again.
I think you will see a reading of less than 1.000 (1 amp), so perhaps something in the range 0.100 to 0.500 (100-500 mA). Then after a few minutes, you may see the current drop below 0.100 and remain there.
If the ECU current either starts below 100 mA or starts higher and falls below 100 mA, you have a totally normal ECU power consumption and not a parasitic drain from the ECU. Every car on the street is doing the same thing and not killing batteries. NOTE: Unplug the meter cable from the 10A socket, and don’t use that socket unless you know that the current you are measuring will be less than 10 amps. That socket is only used to measure current, not volts.
NOW THE BATTERY
The only reliable way to test your battery is to charge it to 100% full charge and then test it with a high current battery tester that puts a heavy load of hundreds of amps on the battery to simulate cranking the starter. After a stated time such as 15 seconds of high load, the voltage is measured just before disconnecting the load. That instantaneous voltage at the end of the timed heavy load determines the battery’s health.
The equipment required to do this costs more than a new battery. If you don’t want to make the investment, you can take the battery to an auto parts store or a mechanic and they can test it for you. If the battery is too discharged to test, they can charge it for you. However, if they put the battery on a charger and it takes only a few minutes to come to full charge, that is a clear indication without further testing that the battery is past its useful life and you need a replacement.
I suspect that your only problem is an old battery that has reached the end of its useful life, and if testing the battery confirms this, then it’s time to replace the battery.
WHAT IF THE BATTERY IS GOOD?
If by chance the battery undergoes a heavy load test and the results are “good battery,” then your charging system should be tested to determine why the battery has such a low charge. Since you’ve already proven that you don’t have a parasitic battery drain from the ECU or anything else, the charging system test would be the next logical step.
